# Rspec - expected Exception with but nothing was raised

Tags: ruby, exception, rspec

I'm new to coding and particularly new to Rspec so apologies in advance if this is basic. I'm getting an error:

```
`1) DockingStation does not release broken bikes
 Failure/Error: expect {subject.release_bike}.to raise_error 'No bikes available'
   expected Exception with "No bikes available" but nothing was raised
 # ./spec/docking_station_spec.rb:54:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

The block of code that it's referencing in my spec is:

```
  it 'does not release broken bikes' do
    bike = Bike.new
    bike.report_broken
    subject.dock bike
    expect {subject.release_bike}.to raise_error 'No bikes available'
  end
```

I need to write a bit of code in my other file so that something 'is raised' but I have no idea what. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Cheers.

Comment: What is the `release_bike` method? Probably you want to check from there whether there are any available bikes, and raise an error (`raise "No bikes available"`) if there aren't. Please show your actual code, not just the failing test

Comment: Hello. Sorry, I thought it was bad etiquette to throw in huge chunks of code so tried to make it concise. The release_bike method is as follows in the quotes.

"def release_bike,
    fail 'No bikes available' if empty?,
    bikes.pop,
  end"

and the empty method is just:

"def empty?,
    bikes.empty?,
  end"

There's not enough room in this little box for me to include all the code from both files, apologies. Thanks for your involvement.

Comment: You need to show the essential information. Some people can't make that distinction and post a massive amount of code or just link their repo, which is bad. But in your case the question is impossible to answer with such limited info

Comment: "describe '#release_bike' do,
    it 'raises an error when there are no bikes available' do,
      expect { subject.release_bike }.to raise_error 'No bikes available',
    end,
  end"

Comment: The "essential information" here is the _actual source code_ - the definition of the `release_bike` method and _not_ just the tests. Please copy-paste your code into your _question_.